I can't add parameters to my WordPress site's URL
I'm a Web Development Student and it's the first time I use WordPress. But, for my internship, I have to add a page to a website using WordPress.
So, on my WordPress site page, I display data retrieved from an API. I use the wpgetapi and code snippet plugins to first retrieve the API and then display it via PHP code.
I would like to be able to paginate so that I don't have to display all the data at once. I did some research and found a method to paginate by adding a parameter to my website's URL.
Like this :
<div class="pagination">
 
<?php
    if ($total_pages > 1) {
        echo '<nav class="pagination">';
        if ($page > 1) {
            // Previous button
            echo '<a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '">&laquo; Previous</a>';
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
            if ($i == $page) {
                // Current page
                echo '<span>' . $i . '</span>';
            } else {
                // Other page button
                echo '<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }
        if ($page < $total_pages) {
            // Next button
            echo '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '">Next &raquo;
</a>';
        }
        echo '</nav>';
    }
?>

</div>

Except that every time I want to add this query parameter by clicking on the link made for it, no parameter is added. I have the 301 Redirect plugin active which removes this parameter every time. But even when I disable it, the problem persists. Do you have any idea where this could come from?
Thanks in advance.

The API must support such mechanism otherwise your request will be for all results. If you want to just limit visualy how many to show you can use JS. With PHP you need to retrive ?page $_GET['page'] and pass it to your API request.

@Snuffy Thank you for your response.
I am using Kernex as an API and with wpgetapi I cannot have a request per page. My problem is not how to retrieve ?page but rather that this parameter remains in the URL.

For the param issue could be the plugin you mention or other plugin. After you disable the plugin clear cache and try again. Some 301 redirect plugins even disabled keep the .htaccess file unchanged and redirection still will work. Wordpress wont remove ? params on its own. If its not plugin could be the theme ? Switch to default 2024 theme (https://themes.getmotopress.com/2024/?page) as you can see wont remove it.

Okay, I see. After disabling the 301 redirect, I then cleared the cache and I don't have any other plugins that could be removing the parameter. So, would this mean the theme is preventing this?

As i said these redirections could be still active in the .htaccess file. You can switch the theme just to test .

Okay, I have to talk about this with my internship supervisor
